# Weird behaviour of reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

In my app, when a tableview cell is reloaded like this

```
let editItemView = view.viewWithTag(12) as! UITableView
let indexPath = editItemView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: editItemView))
editItemView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

and the new height is less than the old, sometimes (particularly when the cell is at the bottom of the view), parts of the old content of the cell stays at the screen covering the cells below. All cells heights are correct and when the corrupt cell (@ its new size) is moved out of view, it disappears. However, a **reloadData** works as expected. Does anybody know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: the code was removing a button from the same **UITableView** *before* the **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** like this:

```
if let dcButton = view.viewWithTag(20) as? UIButton{
    dcButton.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Putting this code *after* the **reloadRowsAtIndexPaths** ended the unpredictable behaviour of the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bracketing the call?

```
editItemView.beginUpdates()
editItemView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
editItemView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes, I did, no effect. Also, the Apple docs says about beginUpdates(): "Begins a series of method calls that insert, delete, or select rows and sections of the table view."